I want to save the value of a counter in a list and display it later
I am making a cls file for an exercise sheet and in this one I make an exo environment with a counter and a sol environment that saves the solution to display it at the end of the document.
To do so I used a list to save all the solutions. The only problem I have is the counter to keep track of the exercise number is not displayed.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newenviron}


\newcounter{exercice}
\def\sollist{}
\listadd{\sollist}{}

\newrobustcmd{\solexpandingcommand}[1]{%
\listgadd{\sollist}{#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\solvarexpandingcommand}[1]{
\listxadd{\sollist}[#1]
}

\newenvironment{exo}[1][]{
\refstepcounter{exercice}\par\medskip
   \noindent\textbf{Exercice~\theexercice.} #1 \rmfamily
   }
   {
   \medskip
   }


\newenviron{sol}{
}{
    \expandafter\solexpandingcommand{\noindent\textbf{Solution:}} 
    \solvarexpandingcommand{\arabic{exercice}}
    \expandafter\solexpandingcommand\expandafter{\envbody}
    \expandafter\solexpandingcommand\expandafter{\par\medskip}
}


\AtBeginDocument{
    \newrobustcmd{\showlist}[1]{
    #1%
    }%
}
\AtEndDocument{
    \newpage
    \section{Solution}
    \forlistloop{\showlist}{\sollist}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exo}
    What is $1 + 1$.
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
    The answer to $1+1$ is $2$.
\end{sol}
\begin{exo}
    What is $2+2$.
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
    The answer to $2+2$ is $4$.
\end{sol}
\end{document}


This does not show the number of the solution but just a | symbol.
Before that I had the line which write the solution as :
\edef\tmp{\theexercice}
\expandafter\solexpandindcommand{\noindent\textbf{Solution~\tmp:}}

But it was not working either.
Does someone has a solution for this ?

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable. It should start with \documentclassand end with \end{document}

Neither does one know what \listadd does—probably it is from package etools, but who knows for sure?—nor does one know why unused \solvarexpandingcommand is defined, but maybe—blind guessing—something like expl3's f-type-expansion does the trick.
\refstepcounter, when hyperef is loaded, also places an anchor/a destination for hyperlinks, so with this answer \refstepcounteris placed behind \noindent to make sure the anchor is not placed with the last line of the preceding paragraph.
As it is not clear whether the work in question is to be used privately only, it is recommended to learn about expansion and proper usage of \expandafter and about placement of % before attempting to write documentclasses that are to be used by other people.
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\begingroup\catcode`\^^@=12 %
\def\Nullcharconst{\endgroup\newcommand\Nullcharconst{`^^@}}%
\Nullcharconst

\newcounter{exercice}
\newcommand\sollist{}
\listadd{\sollist}{}

\newenvironment{exo}[1][]{%
  \par\medskip
  \noindent
  \refstepcounter{exercice}%
  \textbf{Exercice~\theexercice.} #1 \rmfamily
}{%
  \medskip
}%
\newenviron{sol}{}{%
  \listgadd{\sollist}{\noindent\textbf{Solution:}}%
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral\Nullcharconst\arabic{exercice}}{\listgadd{\sollist}}%
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\envbody}{\listgadd{\sollist}}%
  \listgadd{\sollist}{\par\medskip}%
}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newrobustcmd{\showlist}[1]{#1}%
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \newpage
  \section{Solution}%
  \forlistloop{\showlist}{\sollist}%
}%


First off thank you very much for your answer, the package is inded for private use.
You seem very knowledgeable about the subject, do you know where I can find detailled information about the usage of $\expandafter$ and $%$ and can you explain or give a link that could help me understand the solution you gave.
Thank you very much.

@Florian How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?

@Florian Donald E. Knuth: The TeXbook . ;-)

@Florian Probably also of interest: An overview over TeX's different stages of processing things: Define commands without the need for brackets . An overview over how TeX gathers macro arguments: How does TeX look for delimited arguments?

Thank you very much :-)

\romannumeral\Nullcharconst is \romannumeral`^^@ whereby ​`^^@ is a character constant with TeX's ^^-notation for the null-character, thus this denotes the number 0.For one thing \romannumeral doesn't return any token for the number 0.For another thing, when TeX is gathering a -quantity and finds a character constant, TeX keeps expanding things until it finds some unexpandable token. If that is a space-token, it gets removed(!) as . So the construct serves the purpose of keeping TeX expanding subsequent things until finding a non-expandable token.
